# Find all odd numbers $n$ such that $q= \frac{\ln(3n+1)}{6\ln(2)}$ is also an odd number.

Tags: logarithms

Find all odd numbers $n$ such that

$$ q= \dfrac{\ln(3n+1)}{6\ln(2)}$$ is also an odd number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation is equivalent to:
$$q=\log_{64}(3n+1)$$
or
$$n=\frac{64^q-1}3$$

Since $64\equiv 1\pmod 3$, $n$ is an integer. And since $64^q-1$ is odd, $n$ is odd. So you only have to substitute $q$ for odd numbers, and you get the possible values of $n$.

Comment: Your statement "since $64^q−1$  is odd, $n$ is odd" is not true in itself, since an odd number divided by another odd number may be even.

Comment: No, it cant be even.

Comment: If you divide a number that has not the factor $2$ (that is, an odd number), the factor $2$ can't appear from the thin air in the quotient.